# Probability of multiple prizes for multiple entries

Tags: probability, binomial-distribution, odds

Here's the situation:

- There are 300 hunting permits given out for a specific area.
- 5059 applications are submitted for the permits
- Of those 5059 applications, 6 of them are mine.
- Every applicant can also submit up to 6 applications.
- I (and every other applicant) can only draw one permit.
- I'm not sure how many other people have submitted applications, only that the total number of applications is 5059

What are my odds of drawing a hunting permit?  If you could show me the math behind this, it would be much appreciated. I'd love to create a JavaScript tool for figuring these sort of probabilities.

Comment: The logic in your introductory sentence looks invalid.  First, you cast aspersions on your profession by suggesting that teaching English implies one is not good at math.  Counterexamples abound.  Second, whether or not that implication is true and whether or not you do teach English (although I don't doubt you do), that has nothing to do with whether your question would be easy for anyone else to answer. ;-)

Comment: Fair enough. I rescind my previous statement... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that:

- all applications are equivalent (essentially nothing differentiates them and they are selected at random),
- any individual can submit as many applications as they desire,
- any individual can win all of the available permits, given they submit enough applications to do so.

I think this is a simple hypergeometric distribution:

$$P(X=k)=\frac{{N\choose{k}} {N-K\choose{n-k}}}{N\choose n}$$

where $k$ is the number of successes from $n$ draws from the population, $N$ is the population from which you draw and $K$ is the number of possible successes in the population. The hypergeometric distribution assumes samples are drawn *without replacement*.

So for your example, $N=5059$, $K=6$, $n=300$ and the probability of having **one** ($k=1$) permit selected would be:

$$P(X=1)=\frac{{5059\choose{1}} {5059-6\choose{300-1}}}{5059\choose 300}=0.2623\dots$$

The probablity of having **at least one** successful application is:

$$P(X\geq 1)=1-P(X=0)=1-\frac{{5059-6\choose{300}}}{5059\choose 300}=0.3072\dots$$

For your information, the **expected number** of successful applications from the ones you submitted is:

$$\mathbb{E}[X]=0.3558\ldots$$

---

As was stated in the comments, **the answer to this question is more complex due to the fact it is dependent on the number of applicants** in the pool. To save myself some added complexity, let's assume that the actual population of applications is:

$$N=5064\,\,\text{ applications}$$

The reason for this is that if $N=5059$ then it is not evenly divisible by 6 (the maximum number of applications per person) and this leads to some tedious complexity later on. The reason I chose to set $N=5064$ and not $N=5058$ is that it will lead to a more conservative estimate of the probability.

Further to this, let's assume we are only interested in whether we achieve the one permit $(k=1)$.

Because each applicant can only receive *one* permit and the maximum number of applications per person is $K=6$, then the minimum number of applicants has to be:

$$y_{\text{MIN}}=\frac{5064}{6}=844 \,\,\text{ applicants}$$

Each of these applicants has $K=6$ applications. Denote $W_{i}$ as the probability of the event of our application being selected on the $i\text{th}$ draw (from 300 draws), and $L_{i}$ the probability of the event of it not being selected. Note that when an individual's application is successful, all of their other applications are removed from the population. Thus, the probability of having one application selected from 300 draws is:

$$\begin{align}
\text{Pr}(X=1)&=W_{1}+L_{1}W_{2}+L_{1}L_{2}W_{3}+\ldots +L_{1}\cdots L_{299}W_{300}\\
&=\bigg(\frac{6}{5064}\bigg)
+\bigg(\frac{5058}{5064}\bigg)\bigg(\frac{6}{5058}\bigg)
+\bigg(\frac{5058}{5064}\bigg)\bigg(\frac{5052}{5058}\bigg)\bigg(\frac{6}{5052}\bigg)
+\ldots \\
&=300\times\bigg(\frac{6}{5064}\bigg)\\
&=0.3555
\end{align}$$

Thus, this is essentially an upper bound on the probability. We still need to derive a lower bound. This can be achieved by noting the maximum number of applicants (including you) is:

$$y_{\text{MAX}}=5064-6+1=5059$$

This assumes that all other applicants submit 1 application and you submit 6. This reduces to a simple hypergeometric distribution again as I showed above.

$$P(X=1)=\frac{{5064\choose{1}} {5064-6\choose{300-1}}}{5064\choose 300}=0.2621$$

Thus, depending on the number of applicants, $y$, the answer is:

$$844\leq y\leq 5059$$

$$0.2621\leq P(X=1)\leq 0.3555$$

Comment: I think an answer like this cannot generally be correct. The reason is that the answer must depend on the details of other permit applications.  Take two extremes. One is that 299 or fewer people submitted applications--but most people submit multiple applications, totaling 5059.  In this case all applicants would get a permit, assuming at most one permit is granted to each applicant. Another extreme is that 5059-6=5053 other people have each submitted one application apiece (but since one person submitted 6 applications, this assumption is implausible) : that is the value you have calculated.

Comment: @whuber Thanks for your input. What you say makes perfect sense. I'll edit my assumptions for my solution so that my solution is valid, given those assumptions.

Comment: First off, THANK YOU for taking the time to help me try to sort this out. I realized that I left out important info regarding the draw permit (only a maximum of 1 permit is potentially awarded to an individual) and I edited my question accordingly. Would that make your calculation of .2623 correct for this situation?

Comment: @ErikTJohnson I've made an edit to my answer. Hopefully I didn't mess anything up as it was a very quick look. I had to assume a different $N$ because it was going to create too much complexity for me to calculate the upper bound for the probability without any software on hand.